# CSS Minification script misses some CSS3 properties

Tags: javascript, html, css, minify

I have a lot of newer CSS3 properties in my CSS file, and I'm afraid that the minification tool I'm using is missing a lot of these properties:

```
.big-blue-button:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #0994d2;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#0994d2,#0db5e0);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0994d2,#0db5e0);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0994d2',endColorstr='#0db5e0')";
}
```

--> with minification

```
.big-blue-button:hover {
text-decoration: none;
background: 0;
-ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0994d2',endColorstr='#0db5e0');
}
```

Does anyone know of a good minification script that works with all the newer CSS properties? Note that I need to do this minification **from a script**, so it must be executable (as opposed to a copy/paste option).

Comment: I love this http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/main/csscompressor/

Comment: What tool are you using?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/django-compress/

Comment: http://prefixr.com with checkbox "Compress My Code"

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/ is a great tool. It can be used from the command line or a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look to [minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/)

"Combines, minifies, and caches JavaScript and CSS files on demand to speed up page loads."

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Pretty Diff](http://prettydiff.com/?m=minify) and watched it fail?  I just updated to support this edge case.  Try it again and see if it does what you need.  If you have not tried it already then pretend it has always worked brilliantly and does absolutely your heart could possibly desire.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below online tool for Minify your CSS.

[MinifyCSS](http://www.minifycss.com/css-compressor)

Regards
m